# how to bind two events on two elements to one function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have a input text and a button

I want two events, button.on click and input.on KeyEnterPress to bind to one same function

How can I do that?

```
$('#search.onClick OR $searchText.onKeyEnterPress')
```

Comment: you can add same class to both elements and attach an event of click and keyup.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vfttf4Lx/ check this demo for sample

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vfttf4Lx/1/ you can also check the event type if you want to capture only keyup for input text check the event type and do a condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function to call:

```
function myfunc(event){
   // some code
}
```

You can do

```
$('#search').add($searchText).on('click keyup', myfunc);
```

OR if you ONLY want those on one (not both) do:

```
$('#search').on('click', myfunc);
$($searchText).on('keyup', myfunc);
```

NOTE Not clear if that last is a jQuery object but if so:

```
$searchText.on('keyup', myfunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the approach you want or not?

```js
$('.but').on('click keyup',function(){
 if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     console.log('1');
     return;
  }
 console.log('1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="but">
```

Comment: Why mix event handling styles (i.e., why not use `on` for both)? Most jQuery I've seen would also chain them off the selector instead of getting the elements twice. Minor points, but worth mentioning.

Comment: check this one, i `bind` in one event handler.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I read the selectors as being the same in your code, but you're right, the OP is using different ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doOneThing(){
    console.log('Do one thing.');
}

$("#search_input").on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
         doOneThing();
    }
});

$("#search_button").on('click', function(e) {
     doOneThing();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ruta44b3/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="searchText" placeholder="Type soemthing" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="search">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#search').on('click', execute);
  $('#searchText').on('keyup', execute);
});

function execute() {
  alert('Event Fired');
}
```